# Having issue understanding part of blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, block

I am trying to wrap my head around block programming, and currently stuck in this problem

```
char *myCharacters[3] = { "TomJohn", "George", "Charles Condomine" };
qsort_b(myCharacters, 3, sizeof(char *), ^(const void *l, const void *r) {
    char *left = *(char **)l;
    char *right = *(char **)r;
    return strncmp(left, right, 1); 
});
```

On second line the block parameter `^(const void *l, const void *r)`, from where it is getting its parameter values.

From the Apple [Block Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1) documentation:

> **Blocks with Cocoa**
>
> Several methods in the Cocoa frameworks take a block
>   as an argument, typically either to perform an operation on a
>   collection of objects, or to use as a callback after an operation has
>   finished. The following example shows how to use a block with the
>   NSArray method sortedArrayUsingComparator:. The method takes a single
>   argument—the block. **For illustration, in this case the block is
>   defined as an NSComparator local variable:**

What is the meaning of "in this case the block is defined as an NSComparator local variable"?

This is the code sample provided

```
NSArray *stringsArray = @[ @"string 1",
                         @"String 21",
                         @"string 12",
                         @"String 11",
                         @"String 02" ];
static NSStringCompareOptions comparisonOptions = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch |
                                                  NSNumericSearch |
                                                  NSWidthInsensitiveSearch |
                                                  NSForcedOrderingSearch;
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSComparator finderSortBlock = ^(id string1, id string2) {
    NSRange string1Range = NSMakeRange(0, [string1 length]);
    return [string1 compare:string2 
                    options:comparisonOptions 
                      range:string1Range
                     locale:currentLocale];
};
NSArray *finderSortArray = [stringsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:finderSortBlock];     
NSLog(@"finderSortArray: %@", finderSortArray);
```

Where is `^(id string1, id string2)` getting its parameter values?

Comment: NSComparator is actually a block typecasted as follows `typedef NSComparisonResult (^NSComparator)(id obj1, id obj2);`  same way as `typedef double NSTimeInterval;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSComparator` is actually a block typecasted as follows, `typedef NSComparisonResult (^NSComparator)(id obj1, id obj2);` same way as `typedef double NSTimeInterval;` or `typedef long NSInteger;`. Since it is a block, the format is slightly different with arguments. Basically `NSComparator` is a block which accepts two params `obj1` and `obj2` and returns an `NSComparisonResult` value to denote the ordering of the two objects. It can return  `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame` or `NSOrderedDescending`. This can be used by `sortedArrayUsingComparator` to repeatedly compare two objects in array and sort it based on that. This also helps in implementing our own implementation for sorting. When the sorting happens this block is called by `sortedArrayUsingComparator` and gives values to `obj1` and `obj2` and executes the `NSComparator` block. From that block it returns `NSComparisonResult` based on the comparison we implemented.